# Websockets - onclose - server/client - internet connection drop

Tags: java, websocket, connection-close

I have **client-server application**, **client is based on Java Desktop** Application, and **server is web application with endpoint exposed** and deployed tomcat.

**Does `@OnClose` handles below scenarios.** Can i send some message to server end point when it comes to `@OnClose` method.

I need to handle scenario where client connection closes due to

1.) Internet drop connection

2.) System goes in Hibernate mode.

Server can have my clients connections open.

Here is my client code

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class ChatroomClientEndPoint {
  Session session = null;

   public ChatroomClientEndPoint() {
        URI uri;

        try {

            uri = new URI("endpoint url");

            ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(this, uri);
            System.err.println("Connection found");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("No connection found-->" + ex);
        }

    }


    @OnOpen
    public void processOpen(Session session) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        session.setMaxIdleTimeout(60000 * 60 * 24);     //websocket session timeout =1 day
        this.session = session;

    }


    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(String message) throws JSONException {
    // on receiving messages from server, sends desktop notifications
    }

    public void disConnect() throws IOException {
        sendMessage("close");
    }
 }
```

** This code is already developed, and i think they have not implemented `@OnClose` because they **send close message** to the server, server then removes that session from its list.

Can `@OnClose` help in case of above failures like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround for this.

Once your internet connection goes down, socket channel remain intact, and client can no more send messages.

What i did, whenever request come to my server endpoint , i ask client **"if it is connected"**, then max i wait for 3 seconds to get the response, failure to do so, it means socket is not connected.